# Какой способ является оптимальным для парсинга огромных XML файлов?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, xml, big-data

Как известно в PHP есть множество способов распарсить XML. Какой способ стоит использовать для парсинга огромного файла, чтобы не уронить сервер и выполнить парсинг с максимальной скоростью?

Comment: что именно вам нужно достать из этого файла? какие дальнейшие действия планируются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте потоковые парсеры, например XMLReader. Работает довольно таки шустро при минимальных потреблениях ресурсов. Пример работы с ним:

```
    <?php

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("tooBig.xml");
while ($reader->read()) {
  switch ($reader->nodeType) {
  case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
     if ($reader->localName == "entry") {
        if ($reader->getAttribute("ID") == 5225) {
           while ($reader->read()) {
              if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT) {
                 if ($reader->localName == "title") {
                    $reader->read();
                    echo $reader->value;
                    break;
                 }
                 if ($reader->localName == "entry") {
                    break;
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Также можно использовать SAX парсер, но работать с ним сложнее... Пример  XMLReader взят [отсюда](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xmlphp2/index.html), там же можно посмотреть пример для SAX парсера. Также пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ikfi.ru/article/parsim-xml-s-pomoschju-xmlreader)

Answer (score 0):

Для действительно больших файлов рекомендую использовать `xml_parser_create()`. При его использовании можно добиться действительно малого потребления памяти. Но в этом случае во время парсинга необходимо будет куда-то сохранять промежуточные данные (в файл или базу данных).

Comment: а примерчик разбора не приведёте?